# JQuery Extract value from a tag in a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

i want to extract value from the string

here is my Code

Js

```
var a = "<strong>1954</strong>im the text";
var pageNum = a.split("<strong>").slice(1)
alert(pageNum);
```

i simply want to extract value in strong tag i have tried but so far no luck

Comment: jQuery or just Javascript?

Comment: @Nikolaj Zander- please see the tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the `strong` element inside the `div` and then get its contents using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var pageNum = $("div").find('strong').text()
```

With the update

```
jQuery(function(){
    var a = '<strong>1954</strong>im the text';
    var pageNum = $(a).filter('strong').text();
    alert(pageNum);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F2hPh/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/feW83/)

Comment: i have to extract from <strong>1954</strong>im the text; width out any div i mean this value i get will be in string

Comment: sorry i forgot the semicolm

Comment: thank you very much that what i wanted and im feeling silly now

Answer (score 2):

```
   var text= $("div strong").text();
```

updated

```
 var text= $(a).filter('strong').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you get your Value from the string without jQuery:

```
var pageNum = a.substring(a.indexOf('<strong>' + 8, ), a.indexOf('</strong>'))
```